# Google maps api from where we get?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to use google maps in my ios application can anyone tell me that from where I will get google maps framework so that i can implement it in my application. 
Is is free or any cost i have to pay for google map library.

Comment: Follow this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#upgrade_from_an_earlier_version.It is help you to integrate Google Map in your ios app.

Comment: can you tell me @Bhumika step by step process of installation of google map sdk in my project and any basic example of implementation

Comment: Have you visited link which i gave you?

Comment: @Bhumika yes I have visited but i am not getting step 3 after installation of cocoa pods

Comment: It is about to create **podfile** in your project.To create podfile visit this link.https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Install+the+API+using+CocoaPods&oq=Install+the+API+using+CocoaPods&aqs=chrome..69i57.292j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=create+podfile+ios

Comment: @Bhumika apple-mac:~ Aayush$ $pod init
-bash: init: command not found
apple-mac:~ Aayush$ $ cd
-bash: $: command not found
apple-mac:~ Aayush$ $ pod init
-bash: $: command not found
this is coming so what to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113486/discussion-between-aakash-and-bhumika).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can [find here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/) in developer.google.com and also find below github links

1. [Link1](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils)
2. [Link2](https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-ios)

Comment: can you tell me @Anand K step by step process of installation of google map sdk in my project and any basic example of implementation

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Google Maps API page](https://developers.google.com/maps/), and check out the iOS section for further information .

Cost depends on the sort of use I think, whether you want a premium access or not. Check the link for further details.